# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation - PowerShell Creating Azure Ad Apps fails

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an Azure DevOps CI/CD wherein I have a PowerShell script to create a new Azure Ad App. Although the Service Principle has permissions granted against the following Graph APIs, yet, it fails with the following exception.

> 2020-12-14T11:49:55.0146669Z ##[error]Error occurred while executing **GetApplications**
> Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
> Message: **Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.**
> RequestId: 1130fbec-3eec-4c8e-a2dd-e134f2c4621f
> DateTimeStamp: Mon, 14 Dec 2020 11:49:54 GMT
> HttpStatusCode: **Forbidden**
> HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
> HttpResponseStatus: Completed

The API permissions that I have for the Service Principle are:
[image]

I use the following script to connect to Azure AD from the pipeline and create the Azure Ad App using PowerShell

```
Install-Module AzureAD -Force -Verbose -Scope CurrentUser
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken

Connect-AzureAD -MsAccessToken $graphToken -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id

$ApiAppGuid = New-Guid
$ApiAppStartDate = Get-Date
$vvApiAppName = "dev0-vv-api"
# >>>>>> it must be failing here when trying to get the applications...
$appExists = ($vvApiApp = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($vvApiAppName)'"  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
#... rest of the code that call New-AzureADApplication
```

Also, when I put the `$graphToken`in `jwt.io`, it correctly shows the API permissions I've assigned to the Service Principle from Azure Portal.

[image]

I have no idea why it keeps failing despite the permissions consents granted! Any ideas highly appreciated - this is now almost taking a day.

Comment: Could you try `Get-AzureADMSApplication` instead? It's a bit dumb but there is a chance the cmdlet is using AAD Graph API and those app permissions don't work there :\

Comment: that easily fixed the problem. very much appreciated - massive help! does that also mean I can remove all the api permissions from the application now? as it seems it's not picking them up?

Comment: I think Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy would be enough from the permissions you listed. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: nope - that's actually what I meant. I'll try that with only `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` to see if it still works fine

Comment: @Ali Note that `AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All` is an *very* privileged permission. Consider using a [custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-create) which includes the [permission to grant permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-consent-permissions) subject to an [app consent policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/manage-app-consent-policies), and use a custom consent policy which only includes the permissions you really need your CI/CD pipeline to be able to grant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, `Get-AzureADApplication` uses Azure AD Graph API, and it is likely the given MS Graph API application permissions do not work there.
Some permissions do work in AAD Graph as well, but if it is a permission that was created later, it won't be supported.

So the solution is to use `Get-AzureADMSApplication` instead, which uses the MS Graph API.
Most scripts should be switched to use these any way since AAD Graph API is being deprecated.